# I got this problem in my private ethereum blockchain(Node is not syncing, Node data write error ,Synchronisation failed, retrying)

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, private

I am new to ethereum and right now getting the ethereum blockchain using geth with

> geth --port 3000 --networkid 58342 --rpc --rpcport 8545 --rpcaddr 10.0.0.2 --rpccorsdomain "*" console

```
INFO [03-20|11:41:12] Block synchronisation started 
WARN [03-20|11:41:12] Node data write error                    err="state node c56d5a…f2fb4a failed with all peers (1 tries, 1 peers)"
WARN [03-20|11:41:12] Synchronisation failed, retrying         err="state node c56d5a…f2fb4a failed with all peers (1 tries, 1 peers)"
> net.peerCount
1
> net.listeningWARN [03-20|11:41:22] Node data write error                    err="state node c56d5a…f2fb4a failed with all peers (1 tries, 1 peers)"
WARN [03-20|11:41:22] Synchronisation failed, retrying         err="state node c56d5a…f2fb4a failed with all peers (1 tries, 1 peers)"

true
> WARN [03-20|11:41:32] Node data write error                    err="state node c56d5a…f2fb4a failed with all peers (1 tries, 1 peers)"
WARN [03-20|11:41:32] Synchronisation failed, retrying         err="state node c56d5a…f2fb4a failed with all peers (1 tries, 1 peers)"
WARN [03-20|11:41:42] Node data write error                    err="state node c56d5a…f2fb4a failed with all peers (1 tries, 1 peers)"
WARN [03-20|11:41:42] Synchronisation failed, retrying         err="state node c56d5a…f2fb4a failed with all peers (1 tries, 1 peers)"
WARN [03-20|11:41:52] Node data write error                    err="state node c56d5a…f2fb4a failed with all peers (1 tries, 1 peers)"
WARN [03-20|11:41:52] Synchronisation failed, retrying         err="state node c56d5a…f2fb4a failed with all peers (1 tries, 1 peers)"
WARN [03-20|11:42:02] Node data write error                    err="state node c56d5a…f2fb4a failed with all peers (1 tries, 1 peers)"
WARN [03-20|11:42:02] Synchronisation failed, retrying         err="state node c56d5a…f2fb4a failed with all peers (1 tries, 1 peers)"
WARN [03-20|11:42:12] Node data write error                    err="state node c56d5a…f2fb4a failed with all peers (1 tries, 1 peers)"
WARN [03-20|11:42:12] Synchronisation failed, retrying         err="state node c56d5a…f2fb4a failed with all peers (1 tries, 1 peers)"
WARN [03-20|11:42:22] Node data write error                    err="state node c56d5a…f2fb4a failed with all peers (1 tries, 1 peers)"
WARN [03-20|11:42:22] Synchronisation failed, retrying         err="state node c56d5a…f2fb4a failed with all peers (1 tries, 1 peers)"
WARN [03-20|11:42:32] Node data write error                    err="state node c56d5a…f2fb4a failed with all peers (1 tries, 1 peers)"
WARN [03-20|11:42:32] Synchronisation failed, retrying         err="state node c56d5a…f2fb4a failed with all peers (1 tries, 1 peers)"
WARN [03-20|11:42:42] Node data write error                    err="state node c56d5a…f2fb4a failed with all peers (1 tries, 1 peers)"
WARN [03-20|11:42:42] Synchronisation failed, retrying         err="state node c56d5a…f2fb4a failed with all peers (1 tries, 1 peers)"
WARN [03-20|11:42:52] Node data write error                    err="state node c56d5a…f2fb4a failed with all peers (1 tries, 1 peers)"
WARN [03-20|11:42:52] Synchronisation failed, retrying         err="state node c56d5a…f2fb4a failed with all peers (1 tries, 1 peers)"
WARN [03-20|11:43:02] Node data write error                    err="state node c56d5a…f2fb4a failed with all peers (1 tries, 1 peers)"
WARN [03-20|11:43:02] Synchronisation failed, retrying         err="state node c56d5a…f2fb4a failed with all peers (1 tries, 1 peers)"
WARN [03-20|11:43:12] Node data write error                    err="state node c56d5a…f2fb4a failed with all peers (1 tries, 1 peers)"
WARN [03-20|11:43:12] Synchronisation failed, retrying         err="state node c56d5a…f2fb4a failed with all peers (1 tries, 1 peers)"
WARN [03-20|11:43:22] Node data write error                    err="state node c56d5a…f2fb4a failed with all peers (1 tries, 1 peers)"
WARN [03-20|11:43:22] Synchronisation failed, retrying         err="state node c56d5a…f2fb4a failed with all peers (1 tries, 1 peers)"
WARN [03-20|11:43:32] Node data write error                    err="state node c56d5a…f2fb4a failed with all peers (1 tries, 1 peers)"
WARN [03-20|11:43:32] Synchronisation failed, retrying         err="state node c56d5a…f2fb4a failed with all peers (1 tries, 1 peers)"
WARN [03-20|11:43:42] Node data write error                    err="state node c56d5a…f2fb4a failed with all peers (1 tries, 1 peers)"
WARN [03-20|11:43:42] Synchronisation failed, retrying         err="state node c56d5a…f2fb4a failed with all peers (1 tries, 1 peers)"
> admin.nodeInfo.enoWARN [03-20|11:43:52] Node data write error                    err="state node c56d5a…f2fb4a failed with all peers (1 tries,
```

Comment: What is you geth version? Are you syncing mainnet or some testnet? Do you have enough disk space?

Comment: my  geth version is

Comment: Geth
Version: 1.8.2-stable
Git Commit: b8b9f7f4476a30a0aaf6077daade6ae77f969960
Architecture: amd64
Protocol Versions: [63 62]
Network Id: 1
Go Version: go1.9.4
Operating System: linux
GOPATH=/go
GOROOT=/usr/local/go testnet

Comment: Geth version:1.8 stable and running testnet

Comment: What is the command line used to launch geth? It seems you do not have enough peers and the version of geth seems correct.

Comment: geth --port 3000 --networkid 58342 --rpc --rpcport 8545 --rpcaddr 10.0.0.2 --rpccorsdomain "*" console

Comment: geth --port 3000 --networkid 58342 --rpc --rpcport 8545 --rpcaddr 10.0.0.2 --rpccorsdomain "*" console i used this command

Comment: i am currently running in ubuntu 16.04LTS

Comment: already connected the one peer ,used this command ,it shows like this                      > net.peerCount
1

Comment: It appears to be a private chain are both nodes using the same genesis file? Do you have enough free disk space? perhaps it is causing the error "Node data write error".

Comment: two nodes using same genesis file only,yes i have disk space

Comment: two nodes using same genesis file only,yes i have disk space 117G

Comment: will you please tell, what is the minimum required disk space?

Comment: Your system appears to be ok, you have enough space, and no obvious error in the command line. I really don't know what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

trying using geth --testnet for the ropsten test net, it will take a few hours to sync or maybe days depending on your connection. otherwise if you want a cop of the main chain you can use geth --light this will give you a light sync of the blockchain that allows you to interact with the main-net. Syncing time should only be about 5-10 mins for --light. you can check sync percentage by opening up a new terminal and using geth --attach for light sync or geth --testnet attach for ropsten. this will allow you to check sync status by using "eth.syncing" you can then compare your current block size against etherscan or ether chain.org.

there are also other options to get a node running on your machine such as testrpc, ganache-cli but these are just local nodes that are a representation of the Ethereum blockchain.

Comment: Sorry to say this,I tried this one whatever you given geth  attach for light sync or geth  --testnet attach but i am getting same above error only in my peer system

Comment: Sorry to say this,I tried this one whatever you given geth  attach for light sync or geth  --testnet attach but i am getting same above error only in my peer system(I connected one system as node and another system as a peer)

Comment: u must have a bad connection, (and a node is a peer)

Comment: geth --light is fully synced once u start getting 1 block header around every 15 seconds

Comment: I got same problem in two systems.If one connection is bad connection, another connection is also i am getting same error ,i connected with two peers (another system also same problem only)

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have two different nodes trying to sync their own versions of chain databases with yours. If that is the case, disconnect the other nodes and try to resync them with the correct node .